# forcefully exit from app using WillPopScope in Flutter

Tags: flutter

> My problem is that I have 3 screens I want to exit from the app on the 3rd screen using WillPopScope.
>   When I use WillPopScope it backs to the 2nd screen...

```
 Future<bool> onWillPop() async {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  if (currentBackPressTime == null ||
      now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
    currentBackPressTime = now;
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Press back again to exit');
    return Future.value(false);
  }

  return Future.value(true);
}



WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: onWillPop,
  child: Scaffold();
```

Answer (score 3):

Unexpected exit from the app is against apple policies, so SystemNavigator.pop () works only with android.
Do the following.

```
Future<bool> onWillPop() async {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  if (currentBackPressTime == null ||
      now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
    currentBackPressTime = now;
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Press back again to exit');
    return Future.value(false);
  }
  SystemNavigator.pop(); // add this.

  return Future.value(true);
}



WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: onWillPop,
  child: Scaffold();
```

Answer (score 3):

As `WillPopScope` was deprecated after **flutter** **v`3.12`**.

The new way to close the **Flutter** application using `PopScope` is here.

```
    PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
        if (didPop) {
          return;
        }
        final NavigatorState navigator = Navigator.of(context);
        final bool? shouldPop = await CustomDialog.show(
          context,
          WarningDialog(
            title: "Are you sure Close?",
            content: "This will remove close the application",
            confirmText: "Close",
            onConfirm: () {
              Navigator.pop(context, true);
            },
            onCancel: () {
              Navigator.pop(context, false);
            },
          ),
        );
        if (shouldPop ?? false) {
          SystemNavigator.pop();
        }
      },
child://Child Widget
)
```

> This is a custom dialogue I have used. but can use `showDialog()` method. But make sure to pass the boolean value with `Navigator.pop(context,false)`,

> `Navigator.pop(context,false)` Must be inside cancel dialogue button.
> `Navigator.pop(context,true)` Must be inside confirm dialogue button.

```
CustomDialog.show(
      context,
      WarningDialog(
        title: "Are you sure Close?",
        content: "This will remove close the application",
        confirmText: "Close",
        onConfirm: () {
          Navigator.pop(context, true);
        },
        onCancel: () {
          Navigator.pop(context, false);
        },
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the Navigator to pop, as I've done here on the onWillPop property of WillPopScope.

```
 Future<bool> onWillPop() async {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  if (currentBackPressTime == null ||
      now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
    currentBackPressTime = now;
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Press back again to exit');
    return Future.value(false);
  }

  return Future.value(true);
}



WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: if(onWillPop == true) {Navigator.pop(context)},
  child: Scaffold();
```